# Including files in Julia: @everywhere include

Tags: import, parallel-processing, julia

I am trying to include a file with functions in another Julia file. I can do it with

```
include("ImpurityChainLibrary.jl")
```

However, when I do

```
@everywhere include("ImpurityChainLibrary.jl")
```

I get an error (shortened):

```
ERROR: On worker 3: SystemError: opening file /Users/alex/Documents/Julia/Graphene_Adsorbant_Lattice/ImpurityChainLibrary.jl: No such file or directory ...
```

I am running

```
Julia Version 0.6.2
Commit d386e40c17 (2017-12-13 18:08 UTC)
Platform Info:
  OS: macOS (x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0)
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6820HQ CPU @ 2.70GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  BLAS: libopenblas (USE64BITINT DYNAMIC_ARCH NO_AFFINITY Haswell)
  LAPACK: libopenblas64_
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-3.9.1 (ORCJIT, skylake)
```

I use Atom.

Following the minimal example given below, I ran the code and it worked. Then, I created a second file in the same folder as dummy.jl and put in a single line `@everywhere include("dummy.jl")`
.

Then I launch Julia in Atom. I check nprocs() and get 1. When I do addprocs(3), the function call goes through and nprocs() shows 4. When I try to run the `@everywhere include("dummy.jl")` line, I get the error that I described above.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: I think the error message is expressive enough. On your worker node 3 there is no file named `/Users/alex/Documents/Julia/Graphene_Adsorbant_Lattice/ImpurityChainLibrary.jl`.

Comment: Right, but worker 3 is on the same machine. How is it that it’s available to one worker but not the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this question was dismissed too quickly. The behavior can be reproduced outside of the Atom environment. (I'm using Julia 0.6.3 on OSX)

Suppose you have a repository structure:

```
repo/
   src/
       -MyMod.jl
       -script.jl
```

with “MyMod.jl” containing:

```
module MyMod
    export f
    f(x) = 5 * x
end
```

and “script.jl” containing:

```
@everywhere include("MyMod.jl")
using MyMod

for p in workers()
    @show remotecall_fetch(f, p, p)
end
```

From within `repo/src/` you can run `julia -p 4 script.jl` successfully, but from `repo/` you cannot run Julia with multiple processes (i.e. call `julia -p 4 src/script.jl`), since the worker processes attempt to load `repo/MyMod.jl` which doesn’t exist.

This seems to be because `include` interprets relative paths differently from the main process than it does from worker processes. On main "relative" seems to be relative to the script/file, on workers it is relative to the current working directory.

As a workaround I've been using (**edited to handle precompiling):

```
function include_everywhere(filepath)
    include(filepath) # Load on Node 1 first, triggering any precompile
    if nprocs() > 1
        fullpath = joinpath(@__DIR__, filepath)
        @sync for p in workers()
            @async remotecall_wait(include, p, fullpath)
        end
    end
end

include_everywhere("MyMod.jl")
using MyMod
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! I realized that the issue had to do with the paths. The way I dealt with it is to bring the library module file into the same folder as the main script and run it. Before, I kept it inside a folder and the workers weren't finding it.

Answer (score 2):

**DISCLAIMER.** Because the comment field is too short for this, I have compiled an answer instead:

Please include your Julia version as printed in `versioninfo()`. For instance, I am running

```
julia> versioninfo()
Julia Version 0.6.2
Commit d386e40c17 (2017-12-13 18:08 UTC)
Platform Info:
  OS: Linux (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3720QM CPU @ 2.60GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  BLAS: libopenblas (SANDYBRIDGE)
  LAPACK: liblapack
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-3.9.1 (ORCJIT, ivybridge)
```

Then, please make sure to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). With the information you have provided in your question, it is *not* possible for us to reproduce your error. The reason is simple. Check the minimal working example below on my machine:

```sh
~> mkdir dummy
~> cd dummy/
~/dummy> echo "f(x) = 5x" > dummy.jl
~/dummy> julia --procs 4 --eval '@everywhere include("dummy.jl"); @everywhere @show myid(), f(myid())'
(myid(), f(myid())) = (1, 5)
        From worker 4:  (myid(), f(myid())) = (4, 20)
        From worker 3:  (myid(), f(myid())) = (3, 15)
        From worker 5:  (myid(), f(myid())) = (5, 25)
        From worker 2:  (myid(), f(myid())) = (2, 10)
```

Most likely, you have some code that changes directory before calling `@everywhere`. Make sure the error can be reproduced easily on other computers.

**EDIT.** I have added the minimal working example based on OP's modified question below:

```
shell> ls
anotherfile.jl  dummy.jl

shell> cat dummy.jl
f(x) = 5x

shell> cat anotherfile.jl
@everywhere include("dummy.jl")

julia> addprocs(3)
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 2
 3
 4

julia> nprocs()
4

julia> include("anotherfile.jl")

julia> @everywhere @show myid(), f(myid())
(myid(), f(myid())) = (1, 5)
    From worker 2:  (myid(), f(myid())) = (2, 10)
    From worker 3:  (myid(), f(myid())) = (3, 15)
    From worker 4:  (myid(), f(myid())) = (4, 20)
```

As can be seen, the setting you have tried, *i.e.*, adding `anotherfile` and putting `@everywhere include("dummy.jl")` line in it, works as expected, too. Then, you should try opening [an issue](https://github.com/JunoLab/Atom.jl/issues) to let the developers for Atom know about it, if that is the problem, at all.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. I edited the question above to fill in some of the information.

Comment: Sorry @IcyOtter, but your modified minimal example does work, too. I have reproduced your setting on my machine, and it is working. See my modified answer above.